# Sysprep taking an age on EBS custom AMIs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, sysprep

We have created a new custom AMI and followed the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html). When we launch an instance from our custom AMI we have to wait up to an hour for the instance to become usable.

The system logs look like this:

```
2015/05/11 10:10:16Z: Windows is being configured...
2015/05/11 10:11:17Z: Windows is still being configured...
2015/05/11 10:12:18Z: Windows is still being configured...
2015/05/11 10:13:19Z: Windows is still being configured...
2015/05/11 10:40:48Z: Windows is being configured...
2015/05/11 10:09:55Z: Message: Sysprep Start
2015/05/11 10:13:30Z: Message: Sysprep End
2015/05/11 10:41:00Z: AMI Origin Version: 2014.10.15
2015/05/11 10:41:00Z: AMI Origin Name: Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-Base
2015/05/11 10:41:00Z: OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
2015/05/11 10:41:00Z: Language: en-US
2015/05/11 10:41:00Z: EC2 Agent: Ec2Config service v2.2.10.221
2015/05/11 10:41:03Z: Driver: AWS PV Network Device v7.2.4.1
2015/05/11 10:41:03Z: Driver: AWS PV Storage Host Adapter v7.2.4.1
2015/05/11 10:41:03Z: Message: Waiting for meta-data accessibility...
2015/05/11 10:41:03Z: Message: Meta-data is now available.
2015/05/11 10:41:04Z: AMI-ID: ami-63cda614
2015/05/11 10:41:04Z: Instance-ID: i-f1ccc516
2015/05/11 10:41:04Z: Ec2SetPassword: Enabled
2015/05/11 10:41:06Z: Username: Administrator
2015/05/11 10:41:06Z: Password: <Password>password</Password>
2015/05/11 10:41:08Z: RDPCERTIFICATE-SUBJECTNAME: WIN-BNUAEECNDU8
2015/05/11 10:41:08Z: RDPCERTIFICATE-THUMBPRINT: yudgiqwy
2015/05/11 10:42:15Z: Message: Product activation was successful
2015/05/11 10:42:15Z: Message: Ec2Config Service is rebooting the instance. Please be patient.
2015/05/11 10:47:19Z: AMI Origin Version: 2014.10.15
2015/05/11 10:47:19Z: AMI Origin Name: Windows_Server-2012-R2_RTM-English-64Bit-Base
2015/05/11 10:47:19Z: OS: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
2015/05/11 10:47:19Z: Language: en-US
2015/05/11 10:47:19Z: EC2 Agent: Ec2Config service v2.2.10.221
2015/05/11 10:47:19Z: Driver: AWS PV Network Device v7.2.4.1
2015/05/11 10:47:19Z: Driver: AWS PV Storage Host Adapter v7.2.4.1
2015/05/11 10:47:20Z: Message: Waiting for meta-data accessibility...
2015/05/11 10:47:20Z: Message: Meta-data is now available.
2015/05/11 10:47:20Z: AMI-ID: ami-63cda614
2015/05/11 10:47:20Z: Instance-ID: i-f1ccc516
2015/05/11 10:47:20Z: Ec2SetPassword: Disabled
2015/05/11 10:47:20Z: RDPCERTIFICATE-SUBJECTNAME: IP-C0A8E110
2015/05/11 10:47:20Z: RDPCERTIFICATE-THUMBPRINT: aidsgiusdas
2015/05/11 10:47:22Z: Message: Windows is Ready to use
```

As you can see on this occasion the build took nearly 40 minutes (and the instance failed to join the domain but thats a seperate issue)

Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on here? We are guessing that Sysprep is to blame but cannot verify this.